# Amazon Redshift Spectrum external csv table with dynamic input csv column order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I created an external table

```
                    create external table a_schema.my_table(
                        col_a varchar(10),
                        col_b varchar(10),
                    )
                    row format delimited
                    fields terminated by ','
                    stored as textfile
                    location 's3://some-url.com/upload/'
                    table properties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

and  it seems that any uploaded csvs **MUST** match the exact column order specified in this table. Is there a way I can upload CSVs where the columns dont match the exact order here?

for instance this csv would work fine,

```
col_a,col_b
foo,bar
```

however this one wont,

```
col_b,col_a
bar,foo
```