# Load Redshift Spectrum external table with CSVs with differing column order

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69803123/amazon-redshift-spectrum-external-csv-table-with-dynamic-input-csv-column-order) got no answer and I have a similar question, though I'll expand it.

Suppose I have 3 CSV files in `s3://test_path/`. I want to create an external table and populate it with the data in these CSVs. However, not only does column order differ across CSVs, but some columns may be missing from some CSVs.

**Is Redshift Spectrum capable of doing what I want?**

`a.csv`:

```
id,name,type
a1,apple,1
a2,banana,2
```

`b.csv`:

```
type,id,name
1,b1,orange
2,b2,lemon
```

`c.csv`:

```
name,id
kiwi,c1
```

I create the external database/schema and table by running this in Redshift query editor v2 on my Redshift cluster:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL SCHEMA test_schema
FROM DATA CATALOG
DATABASE 'test_db'
REGION 'region'
IAM_ROLE 'iam_role'
CREATE EXTERNAL DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_schema.test_table (
  "id" VARCHAR,
  "name" VARCHAR,
  "type" SMALLINT
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://test_path/'
TABLE PROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
;
```

I expect `SELECT * FROM test_schema.test_table` to yield:

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | apple | 1 |
| a2 | banana | 2 |
| b1 | orange | 1 |
| b2 | lemon | 2 |
| c1 | kiwi | NULL |

Instead I get:

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | apple | 1 |
| a2 | banana | 2 |
| 1 | b1 | NULL |
| 2 | b2 | NULL |
| kiwi | c1 | NULL |

It seems Redshift Spectrum cannot match columns by name across files the way `pandas.concat()` can with data frames with differing column order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your data needs to be transformed to align the data between files.  Your Spectrum DDL specifies that the first row of the CSVs is ignored so the information you need isn't even being read.

If you want to have these files usable as one Spectrum table you will need to transform them to align columns and store new files to S3.  You can do this with Redshift if you also have a support piece of code reading the column order from each file.  You could write a Lambda to do this easily or if your CSV files are fairly simple then a Glue crawler will work.  Almost any ETL tool can do this as well.  Lots of choices but these files are not Spectrum ready as is.

Comment: > "You can do this with Redshift if you also have a support piece of code reading the column order from each file."

I'm interested in this idea. Where can I get more info?

Comment: To be clear this would be a process for converting these files into a standard format, not a process that will allow RS to use them "as is".  My thought in this situation would be to ingest the files and then export them to S3 in a standard format and high-performance format like Parquet.  This could also add partitioning to the data that isn't possible with the original files.  There are a number of ways to do this but the question is about doing this w/ Redshift and minimal other tooling. 1/

Comment: I would write a Lambda function that when given an S3 file would read the first line of the file to see the column order.  This function would then generate the SQL to read this file - this could be a Spectrum table DDL or a COPY command.  I lead toward COPY but either will work.  Then the data can be UNLOADED (as csv, parquet, orc etc. as you like) to a new s3 location with the standard columns and ordering.  2/

Comment: The best answer MAY be to process a set of files at once to that larger s3 objects can be made and/or partitioned files can be produced w/ reasonable sizes.  I'd want to make a step function that orchestrated the lambdas that would read an appropriate set of files in RS (w/ COPY).  Then UNLOAD the partitioned files to S3.  3/

Comment: The last consideration is how to handle new data arriving.  Does this need to be combined with other files?  How quickly do new files need to be accessible in RS?  I'd think about a process that has older files combined and partitioned but newer files being just copies of the original files converted.  Then I'd have a view that spans two spectrum tables - one for the large older data and one for the recent, unoptimized data.  Once a week a process can come through and optimize the new data into the old data and reset the view.  The need to do this is dependent on your situation. 4/4